# findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock nested ios

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am developing app using ios, swift and parse.com as backend.
My problem is I need one query object result in second query object like below code. but when i use below code GUI become unresponsive for some time because of findObjects() method. I have used findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() instead but than tableview self.posts display only one record in tableview. I have 10 record in post table.
Can you guide me proper way how to resolve below issue.Actually I does not want to use findObjects() method.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
var fquery = PFQuery(className: "Friends")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    friendArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    fquery.whereKey("whosefriend", equalTo: object["postusername"])
                    var fobjects = fquery.findObjects()
                    for fobject in fobjects {
                        friendArray.append(fobject["friendname"] as String)
                    }
                    if (contains(friendArray, user["fullname"] as String)) {
                        let post = Post(.......)
                        self.posts.append(post)
                    }
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this already? If you don't want to use findObjects() then why are you?

Comment: You definitely would rather not use findObjects because that's synchronous and will block the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have tried to use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock instead of findObjects but problem is it is asynchronous function so data does not getting properly, so i have used findObjects so I get data and do process.

Comment: You can also give me other solution for my above problem, I wan to just display post on page only if login user is a friend of "posted user".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve the issue by using relational query.

```
var query = PFQuery(classWithName: "Post")
var fQuery = PFQuery(className:"Friends")
fQuery.whereKey("friendname", equalTo: cuser["fullname"])
query.whereKey("postusername", matchesKey:"whosefriend", inQuery:fQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make your "postusername" a pointer column in class Post that points to Friends class and then you would only need one query that would go something like:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
query.includeKey("postusername") //this would include the object that it points to i.e. the Friends object you saved there
```

... then in your `for` loop ...

```
for object in objects! {
    let friend = object["postusername"] // now friend is the Friends object
    let friendName:String = friend["friendname"] as? String
    friendArray.append(friendName)
}
```

Note: this requires you saving "postusername" as a PFObject of Class Friends. Parse iOS docs explain this well.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I have added below line when I add new post                    object["postusername"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Friends",  objectId: PFUser.currentUser().objectId) but when I used your code in for loop I got friend object but friendName getting nil.

Comment: Hey @abcdgef - In the Parse console - you have to change the postusername column to a pointer column that points to Friends class. That also requires you saving an object of Friends class in your postusername column i.e. not just a String. Checkout the Parse ios docs for this. Also, what are you trying to do with `let post = Post(.......)
self.posts.append(post)`

Comment: Hi, I have created pointer column like this, object["postusername"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Friends", objectId: PFUser.currentUser().objectId), is it ok? I does not getting friendname if use your code, Actually when any friend accept invitation, record has been saved in Friends table and post table is for when user add post to table